# Combine Raster and Feature Class selection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2

I've been working on a quite complex analysis with ArcGIS 10.2. But now I'm stuck at a problem...
I have a raster file and a polygon feature.
The Raster file stores information about Zmax, Zmin and the Range.
The Polygon feature stores a height value

What I need: I need to select Polygons with a specific value (above or below Zmax) that are within a certain distance to the raster cell with the specific Zmax value.

I know I can work around and use raster to point and then make an SQL selection (by location and by attribute); select all the points = specific Zmax + select polygons within the certain distance + select out of this the ones with the specific value

But I was wondering whether there is a shorter way/possibility to automate the whole process? I've been working with model builder before but I'm not sure if model builder can be used to automate this task

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.